# How to manually set the color of points in plotly express scatter plots

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/ has many scatter plot examples, but not a single one showing you how to set all the points' colours within px.scatter:

```
# x and y given as DataFrame columns
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris() # iris is a pandas DataFrame
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length")
fig.show()
```

I've tried adding `colour = 'red'` etc doesn't work. These examples only show you how to colour by some other variable.

In principle I could add another feature and set it all the same but that seems a bizzare way of accomplishing the task....

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For that you may use the `color_discrete_sequence` argument.

```
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color_discrete_sequence=['red'])
```

This argument is to use a custom color paletter for discrete `color` factors, but if you are not using any factor for `color` it will use the first element for all the points in the plot.

More about discrete color palletes: https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/

Comment: How about for a `go.Surface` which only accepts `surfacecolor`?

Answer (score 7):

As far as I understand your question, I would try to answer it.

The parameter 'color' only accepts the column names. 
In your case, you can consider using update_traces()

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris() # iris is a pandas DataFrame
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length")
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(
        color='red'))
fig.show()
```

Reference: https://plotly.com/python/marker-style/

Comment: Thanks, but that same a truely insane system compared to other plotting packages (ggplot, matplotlib etc...)

Answer (score 5):

You ***do not have to add another feature*** to get what you want here. Thanks to Python's [method chaining](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-unreasonable-effectiveness-of-method-chaining-in-pandas-15c2109e3c69), you can just include `.update_traces(marker=dict(color='red'))` to manually assign any color of your choosing to *all* markers.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
# x and y given as DataFrame columns
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris() # iris is a pandas DataFrame
fig = px.scatter(df,x="sepal_width",                         
                    y="sepal_length"
                 ).update_traces(marker=dict(color='red'))
fig.show()
```

---