# How to define colors in a figure using Plotly Graph Objects and Plotly Express

Tags: python, colors, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

*There are many questions and answers that touch upon this topic one way or another. With this contribution I'd like to clearly show why an easy approch such as `marker = {'color' : 'red'}` will work for `plotly.graph_objects (go)`, but `color='red'` will not for `plotly.express (px)` although color is an attribute of both `px.Line` and `px.Scatter`. ***And*** I'd like to demonstrate why it's awesome that it doesn't.*

---

So, if `px` is supposed to be the [easiest way to make a plotly figure](https://towardsdatascience.com/plotly-express-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-dc941649687c), then why does something as apparently obvious as `color='red'` return the error

> ValueError: Value of 'color' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'.

To put it short, it's because `color` in `px` does not accept an arbitrary color name or code, but rather a variable name in your dataset in order to assign a [color cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59732422/plotly-what-color-cycle-does-plotly-express-follow/59806427#59806427) to unique values and display them as lines with different colors.

Let me demonstrate by applyig a [gapminder](https://www.gapminder.org/data/) dataset and show a scatterplot of `Life expectancy` versus `GDP per capita` for all (at least *most*) countries across the world as of `2007`. A basic setup like below will produce the following plot

#### Figure 1, plot using `go`:

[image]

The color is set by a cycle named [plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59732422/plotly-what-color-cycle-does-plotly-express-follow) but is here specified using  `marker = {'color' : 'red'}`

#### Figure 2, code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.gapminder()
df=df.query("year==2007")

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df['gdpPercap'], y=df["lifeExp"],
                          mode = 'markers',
                          marker = {'color' : 'red'}
                         ))
fig.show()
```

So let's try this with `px`, and assume that `color='red'` would do the trick:

#### Code 2, attempt at scatter plot with defined color using `px`:

```
# imports
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# dataframe
df = px.data.gapminder()
df=df.query("year==2007")

# plotly express scatter plot
px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp",
           color = 'red',
          )
```

#### Result:

> ValueError: Value of 'color' is not the name of a column in
> 'data_frame'. Expected one of ['country', 'continent', 'year',
> 'lifeExp', 'pop', 'gdpPercap', 'iso_alpha', 'iso_num'] but received:
> red

***So what's going on here?***

Answer (score 59, accepted):

*First, if an explanation of the broader differences between `go` and `px` is required, please take a look [here](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/) and [here](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/plotly.graph_objects.html). And if absolutely no explanations are needed, you'll find a complete code snippet at the very end of the answer which will reveal many of the powers with colors in plotly.express*

---

### Part 1: The Essence:

It might not seem so at first, but there are *very* good reasons why `color='red'` does not work as you might expect using `px`. But first of all, if all you'd like to do is [manually set a particular color for all markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63413928/plotly-how-to-manually-set-the-color-of-points-in-plotly-express-scatter-plots/63441672#63441672) you can do so using `.update_traces(marker=dict(color='red'))` thanks to [pythons chaining method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Explain-Python-class-method-chaining). But first, lets look at the deafult settings:

#### 1.1 Plotly express defaults

#### Figure 1, px default scatterplot using `px.Scatter`

[image]

#### Code 1, px default scatterplot using `px.Scatter`

```
# imports
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# dataframe
df = px.data.gapminder()
df=df.query("year==2007")

# plotly express scatter plot
px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp")
```

Here, as already mentioned in the question, the color is set as the first color in the default plotly sequence available through `px.colors.qualitative.Plotly`:

```
['#636EFA', # the plotly blue you can see above
 '#EF553B',
 '#00CC96',
 '#AB63FA',
 '#FFA15A',
 '#19D3F3',
 '#FF6692',
 '#B6E880',
 '#FF97FF',
 '#FECB52']
```

And that looks pretty good. But what if you want to change things and even add more information at the same time?

### 1.2: How to override the defaults and do *exactly* what you want with px colors:

As we alread touched upon with `px.scatter`, the `color` attribute does not take a color like `red` as an argument. Rather, you can for example use `color='continent'` to easily distinguish between different variables in a dataset. But there's so much more to colors in `px`:

---

The combination of the six following methods will let you do ***exactly*** what you'd like with colors using plotly express. Bear in mind that you do not even have to ***choose***. You can use *one*, *some*, or *all* of the methods below at the same time. And one particular useful approach will reveal itself as a combinatino of `1` and `3`. But we'll get to that in a bit. This is what you need to know:

**1.** *Change the color sequence used by px with:*

```
color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet
```

**2.** *Assign different colors to different variables with the* `color` *argument*

```
color = 'continent'
```

**3.** *customize one or more variable colors with*

```
color_discrete_map={"Asia": 'red'}
```

**4.** *Easily group a larger subset of your variables using dict comprehension and `color_discrete_map`*

```
subset = {"Asia", "Africa", "Oceania"}
group_color = {i: 'red' for i in subset}
```

**5.** *Set opacity using `rgba()` color codes.*

```
color_discrete_map={"Asia": 'rgba(255,0,0,0.4)'}
```

**6.** *Override all settings with:*

```
.update_traces(marker=dict(color='red'))
```

---

### Part 2: The details and the plots

The following snippet will produce the plot below that shows life expectany for all continents for varying levels of GDP. The size of the markers representes different levels of populations to make things more interesting right from the get go.

#### Plot 2:

[image]

#### Code 2:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# dataframe, input
df = px.data.gapminder()
df=df.query("year==2007")

px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp",
           color = 'continent',
           size='pop',
          )
```

To illustrate the flexibility of the methods above, lets first just ***change the color sequence***. Since we for starters are only showing *one* category and *one* color, you'll have to wait for the subsequent steps to see the real effects. But here's the same plot now with `color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet` as per step 1:

**1.** *Change the color sequence used by px with*

```
color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet
```

[image]

Now, let's apply the colors from the `Alphabet` color sequence to the different continents:

**2.** *Assign different colors to different variables with the* `color` *argument*

```
color = 'continent'
```

[image]

If you, like me, think that this particular color sequence is easy on the eye but perhaps a bit indistinguishable, you can assign a color of your choosing to one or more continents like this:

**3.** *customize one or more variable colors with*

```
color_discrete_map={"Asia": 'red'}
```

[image]

And this is pretty awesome: Now you can change the sequence and choose any color you'd like for particularly interesting variables. But the method above can get a bit tedious if you'd like to assign a particular color to a larger subset. So here's how you can do that too with a [dict comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension):

**4.** Assign colors to a group using a dict comprehension and `color_discrete_map`

```
# imports
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# dataframe
df = px.data.gapminder()
df=df.query("year==2007")

subset = {"Asia", "Europe", "Oceania"}
group_color = {i: 'red' for i in subset}

# plotly express scatter plot
px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp",
           size='pop',
           color='continent',
           color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet,
           color_discrete_map=group_color
          )
```

[image]

**5.** Set opacity using `rgba()` color codes.

Now let's take one step back. If you think `red` suits Asia just fine, but is perhaps a bit too strong, you can adjust the opacity using a `rgba` color like `'rgba(255,0,0,0.4)'` to get this:

[image]

#### Complete code for the last plot:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# dataframe, input
df = px.data.gapminder()
df=df.query("year==2007")

px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp",
           color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet,
           color = 'continent',
           size='pop',
           color_discrete_map={"Asia": 'rgba(255,0,0,0.4)'}
          )
```

And if you think we're getting a bit too complicated by now, you can override all settings like this again:

**6.** Override all settings with:

```
.update_traces(marker=dict(color='red'))
```

[image]

And this brings us right back to where we started. I hope you'll find this useful!

#### Complete code snippet with all options available:

```
# imports
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# dataframe
df = px.data.gapminder()
df=df.query("year==2007")

subset = {"Asia", "Europe", "Oceania"}
group_color = {i: 'red' for i in subset}

# plotly express scatter plot
px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp",
           size='pop',
           color='continent',
           color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet,
           #color_discrete_map=group_color
           color_discrete_map={"Asia": 'rgba(255,0,0,0.4)'}
          )#.update_traces(marker=dict(color='red'))
```

Comment: Fantastic answer!

Comment: @Dr.H.Lecter Glad you liked it! Out of curiosity, what particular challenge was it that made you search for it? Exactly the same as described in the question? Or something a bit different?

Comment: The more larger question/answer of "How to override the defaults and do exactly what you want with px colors", I could not find easily or quickly the information I was looking for in the documentation.

Comment: @Dr.H.Lecter Thanks for the feedback! I'll actully consider changing the title to "How to override the defaults and do exactly what you want with px colors".

Comment: This is a great answer and a nice gist of the manual. I would like to suggest one edit though. I think it would be important to emphasize in your example that discrete coloring will only work with categorical variables or strings (`continent` in the example). Even if you have a limited set of integers, it will be interpreted as a continuous scale for the colors. So a dictionary like `color_map = {1: "red", 2: "white"}` will not work, but after converting the coloring variable to strings, `color_map = {"1": "red", "2": "white"}` will.

Comment: @malvoisen Thanks for the feedback! That would certainly be a valuable addition to the post!

Comment: @vestland, if you are on the plotly team, I would also like to suggest to make this point more prominent in the manual. It could be that I am missing something, but the switch between discrete and continuous scales was not clear to me reading the manual for `plotly.express.bar`. I used trial and error with your example to figure it out. I eventually also stumbled upon the page called "Discrete Colors in Python" at plotly.com, but would have been nice to find everything in the function's documentation.