# Plotly: How to assign specific colors for categories?

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, plotly, plotly-python

I have a pandas dataframe of electricity generation mix. So it consists of electricity generation by different fuels. I want to assign a specific color to a specific fuel.
[image]
In Matplotlib, it is convenient to assign a specific color to a specific category by passing a list of colors, e.g.

> df.plot(kind="bar",color=["red","green","yellow"]
> [image]

I wasn't able to assign color similarly for plots using Plotly. What would be the best way to assign specific color to specific categories in Plotly?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation on color sequences](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#explicitly-constructing-a-color-sequence) in plotly express, you should be able to explicitly define a color sequence using the parameter `color_discrete_sequence`. Try running:

```
fig=px.bar(df1, title="Electricity generation mix of Germany in TwH (2000-2019)", color_discrete_sequence=["black","grey","lightgrey","red","rosybrown","blue","limegreen","yellow","forestgreen"])
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

If you're aiming to assign a *specific* color to a *specific* fuel then `color_discrete_sequence` may work just fine for you as long as the structure of your dataset never changes. But the way to specify a color per category is best done through:

```
color_discrete_map = <dict>
```

And in your case:

```
fig = px.bar(df, color_discrete_map= {'Coal': 'black',
                                      'Oil': 'grey',
                                      'Gas': 'blue'}
            )
```

This way you won't have to rely on the sequence of variables to match the sequence of your desired colors.

#### Example plot (with a different but structurally identical dataset)

[image]

#### Complete code

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = px.data.stocks().set_index('date')
fig = px.bar(df, color_discrete_map= {'GOOG': 'black',
                                      'AAPL': 'grey',
                                      'AMZN': 'blue',
                                      'FB': 'green',
                                      'NFLX': 'red',
                                      'MSFT':'firebrick'}
            )
fig.show()
```

For other options please take a look at [Plotly: How to define colors in a figure using plotly.graph_objects and plotly.express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63460213/plotly-how-to-define-colors-in-a-figure-using-plotly-graph-objects-and-plotly-e/63460218)? There you will find how to change the color sequence to whatever you want and still specify som exceptions through `color_discrete_map`.

Comment: Agreed. This is the most generalizable method