# How to select a boxplot color in Plotly for individual plots along the x axis?

Tags: python, plotly, boxplot

I currently have a BoxPlot created in Plotly Express, as seen below

[image]

which uses the code:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.box(df, x="issuer.operator.name", y="validity_period", points='all', log_y=True,
            width=2000, height=1000,
            template="simple_white")
                
fig.show()
```

However, I am trying to create the chart such that each box plot is shown in a different color based on the x-axis objects (i.e. Internet Sec Research Group is Blue, Sectigo is red, etc).

I know from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63460213/plotly-how-to-define-colors-in-a-figure-using-plotly-graph-objects-and-plotly-e) post that you can use the parameter `color= '<column heading>'` to choose how the graph is coloured. From the docs, the parameter color is

> Either a name of a column in data_frame, or a pandas Series or array_like object. Values from this column or array_like are used to assign color to marks.

However, when I try to run the code with the additional color parameter such that

```
import plotly.express as px

    fig = px.box(df, x="issuer.operator.name", y="validity_period", color="issuer.operator.name", points='all', log_y=True,
                width=2000, height=1000,
                template="simple_white")
                    
    fig.show()
```

I recieve the following error:

```
KeyError: (nan, '', '', '')
```

How would I go about changing each boxplot's color? Appreciate any help.

Comment: @user1740577, appreciate the edit. Seems I couldn't add an image directly due to my low rep at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- have simulated your data frame
- this works as you require where there are *NaNs* in **issuer.operator.name**
- simulated a *NaN*,  then get same error.  Resolved by `dropna()`

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({"issuer.operator.name":np.random.choice(["Internet Research", "Sectigo"],200),
                  "validity_period":np.random.uniform(1,100,200)*np.random.uniform(.001,1,200)})
df.iloc[random.randint(0,len(df)-1), 0] = np.nan
fig = px.box(df.dropna(), x="issuer.operator.name", y="validity_period", color="issuer.operator.name", points='all', log_y=True,
            width=700, height=1000,
            template="simple_white")
                
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you @Rob Raymond. This seems to have solved the issue as for some reason I didn't think I had any NaN's in the issuer.operator.name. Cheers